# Porting a GAE Django app to Azure AppFabric

Tags: django, google-app-engine, migration, azure, appfabric

I have a GAE+Django app and wanted to port it to Microsoft Azure AppFabric. What would be the best way to do this? It's sort of like a RESTful service with custom output that is neither JSON nor XML. All of the Azure samples force you to output either XML or JSON and I can't seem to find any samples outputting the raw output.

Any help/information will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking to run Django on Windows Azure?  Or are you looking to rewrite the app in some other language/framework?  (If so, what?)

Comment: If it's possible to run a python+django app on AppFabric, I would like to try it. But since that's probably not possible, what's the easiest way to re-write the app for AppFabric hosting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is possible, I haven't tried.

Here's a Channel 9 video on running Python on Windows Azure:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-13-Running-Python-the-censored-edition

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. See https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/other/

Also https://github.com/smarx/pythonrole

So you should even be able to run django.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late to the party, but here's a nicely packaged tutorial for running Django on Azure:

https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/web-app-with-django/

Note that you can also run Linux instances raw in Azure if the rest of the PaaS isn't to your liking.

Comment: Thanks Scott A. I'm no longer looking for answer to this question, but it may help others who are looking for answers.